# How to mention thesis in a paper?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-request, sentence-choice, academic-writing

I've written an academic paper with my master thesis. I need to mention my master thesis in the paper, but I'm not sure what I should write.

Some examples:

1. This paper was derived from my master thesis.
2. This paper has been produced from my master thesis.
3. This paper was based on my master thesis.
4. This paper is extending my master thesis.

Actually I would like to learn the regular sentence in papers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this what you need

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/130772/is-it-normal-to-extract-a-paper-from-a-master-thesis

It gives help on this subject And yes **you must mention it in the paper or it will be "self plagiarism"** if you do not cite the source.

---

Something like this should do the trick.

> This paper is taken from my thesis [title] done in [date] at [school] under the direction of [advisor].

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @Brad. I've changed it a bit: "This paper is taken from the first author's unpublished master thesis “[thesis title]“ done at [school name] under the direction of the second author." It is okay?

Comment: I would imagine, so I am not a lawyer and this is a  little outside of my usual remit. I just try/hope to point people in the right direction.